# How to add extra blank rows in crystal report after loading data in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, addition, rows

I have a quaestion with regards to adding extra blank rows after loading the data. The reason for adding extra blank rows is to achieve the format of the given report. Example, in the traning and seminar table, the given format is 20 rows. If it has only 15 trainings in the record, there should be 5 more blank rows to be added to achieve the format. I hope you get what i am trying to explain.

Comment: I think the easiest way is to add the rows to the dataset programmatically from vb.net.

Comment: @Raphael Thank you for the answer, but i have already found one using the crystal report footer using a formula in the expert to set the conditions.